# Redirect laravel to angular route

Tags: laravel-5, angular7, angular7-router

I need to make laravel redirect to an Angular route.

I'm deploying my first project using Angular7 for front & laravel 5.8 for the API and it works fine in development. However when I build the Angular project and locate it in the public directory of laravel so that I can access it by `http://127.0.0.1:8000/<my project name>` angular route doesn't work if I request a specific link like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/<my project name>/view/data/45`. In this case laravel returns 404 response since this is Angular's route not laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by adding a new route to Laravel routes which redirect whatever it got to the index page of Angular and added the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to my index.html page